# is_test does not exist

Tags: data-processor

From 1.38 to 1.39 something has changed in the way is_test is taken into account. For me, this results in an error and I have created an issue for this: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/dataprocessor/-/issues/99

Does anyone else have this problem? And perhaps a solution?

Comment: just to clarify for everyone, is this is_test specifically related to membership. or also contributions. or more generic than that

Comment: I do not use contributions, just membership, so I cannot be certain.